# My minecraft world is stuck on Creative mode

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I was building a farm house and as I built it, I was in creative mode. After it was built, I decided that I wanted to be in survival mode and just mess around and possibly build my farm house even bigger. Welll..... I can not get out of this weird mode. I do the correct /gamemode and I see my hearts and food bar show up but I'm not able to break blocks as if I'm in survival, they just completely disappear after i break them! Like if I was in creative mode, you know how you break a block and poof its gone, well its like that. I see the little block after i break it but its only for 1 sec. I cant fly or anything when I'm like this just to be clear, I also kill everything with one hit and get no drops and only one experience rolls my way.

I've tried restarting everything and also using a different version than my original 1.8.9 minecraft. Its also on my pc... And another thing, everything works fine in my other saved worlds, Just this particular one, that is messed up.

Comment: Are you *absolutely* sure you're on survival, i.e. `/gamemode 0`, rather than adventure (`/gamemode 2`)?

Comment: I think MCEdit might be able to force a gamemode change?

Answer (score 2):

**You're in adventure mode.** 
 This mode is pretty much survival mode except you cannot break or place most blocks. This mode was added with the intent for use with adventure maps, to prevent players from being able to damage the map, therefore affecting quality of play. 
**The Solution**
Enter the command *exactly* as

```
/gamemode 0
```

Or

```
/gamemode s
```

Or

```
/gamemode survival
```

To make this a better process, edit the game mode on the map select screen, or place the desired command in a command block in a frequently trafficked area of your world and slap a button on it, which will activate the command when you press the button.
*If* none of these methods work, you may have to:

- create a new world
- modify the save manually 
  Or
- download a copy/pasting mod 
  [Here's](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1272389-worldedit-do-really-big-things-in-game-in-game-map) what seems to be a good copy paste mod, although some found it confusing
  Or you can get what appears to be the more popular Schematica mod, which you can find [here.](http://minecraftsix.com/schematica-mod/)

  Note: These are just suggestions, there are plenty of copy paste mods this  choose from.

Answer (score -3):

Well you can try to do something. The easiest way to fix it is to load a backup. But if you don't have a backup, then you can try to do /kill @e and that might fix it.